# Finding config file (vimrc?) for VimR OSX

Tags: macos, vim, vim-r

For the VimR OSX app, I want to change the default vim settings (like default colorscheme, or always having :set number), and read online that there's a vimrc file that should be changed, but for some reason I just can't find it on my computer.

Do you guys know where the vimrc (or whatever the vim config file is called) for VimR is?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VimR, (now?) tracking NeoVim, not Vim, [isn't using *~/.vimrc* by default any more](https://github.com/qvacua/vimr/issues/317#issuecomment-257240501):

> User: I reinstalled VimR recently, and settings from my .vimrc are no longer loaded. Should I create some new dotfile and source .vimrc in it?
>
> Author: NeoVim changed that: https://neovim.io/doc/user/nvim.html#nvim-from-vim

and to quote from the linked NeoVim docs:

> ```
> Transitioning from Vim                *nvim-from-vim*
>
> To start the transition, create ~/.config/nvim/init.vim with these contents:
>
>     set runtimepath^=~/.vim runtimepath+=~/.vim/after
>     let &packpath = &runtimepath
>     source ~/.vimrc
>
> Note: If your system sets `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME`, use that instead of `~/.config`
> in the code above. Nvim follows the XDG |base-directories| convention.
> ```